# In react, how is caching implemented, so that the api need not be called everytime for getting data

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-native

I am working on a react application which gets some data from an api and displays the data in a table. Clicking on the table row navigates to a details page and shows information about the clicked row. Once coming back to the home page(table), the table needs to get loaded again, which calls the api. Instead I need to cache the loaded table so that it doesn't need to call the api everytime after clicking on the row and coming back. How can this be done.

Comment: Check out `redux` or other state management implementations

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Redux Persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). Redux is great, and this allows you to persist your store (great for offline).

Answer (score 0):

You manage it yourself. If you're making your request inside of the component constructor or lifecycle methods and saving it into the component's state, that data will be gone once the component unmounts. So, you need to move to keeping that state *outside* of the component, somewhere that will persist longer than your list's full mount/unmount lifecycle. The most common solution is redux. But conceptually even something like this would work.

```
let tableData = null;

class MyListComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    if (tableData === null) {
      makeTableDataRequest().then(data => {
        tableData = data;
        this.setState({ tableData: data });
      })
    } else {
      this.state = {
        tableData: tableData,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use http caching. Making the request again will return the same response, but the browser will invisibly handle returning it from the cache. Definitely some major tradeoffs doing it this way though.